# How to shear an arrow head in illustrator cc

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I am making a design and I really like the look of one of the arrow heads for a stroke - as seen in the picture.

The design is all on a perspective slant which I have been shearing text to get the desired look. However the arrow head just looks off next to the type. Is there any way to shear it? I tried converting to outlines and that did not work.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your arrowhead to an editable shape. Select it and goto Object > Expand Appearance. Ungroup to separate the stroke and the arrowhead.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the arrow to a symbol, there's not need to expand it, you keep the original stroke and you can shear the symbol. Edit the symbol with double click to change color, type of arrow, etc.

[image: symbol]